# Unable to mount iSCSI shared Datastore on VMware ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, iscsi, datastore

I had an iSCSI Datastore mounted and now am unable to remount it.
There are 2 shares one of which is new and I want to copy the data from the old to the new.
I have created a new datastore with the new shared however the original old one does not mount. Its only available to have a new datastore created against it. 
How can I force it to mount ?

Here is a look in to what I see:

```
[root@esxi-02:~] esxcfg-scsidevs --uids
Primary UID                                                     Other UID                                                       
mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0                                            vml.01000000003443353331303031353130353236313138353434556c74726120
mpx.vmhba33:C0:T0:L0                                            vml.0005000000766d68626133333a303a30                            
mpx.vmhba33:C0:T0:L1                                            vml.0000010000766d68626133333a303a31                            
naa.55cd2e415081a400                                            vml.020000000055cd2e415081a400494e54454c20                      
naa.600140530f8f7a4dd969d4702d9397d2                            vml.0200010000600140530f8f7a4dd969d4702d9397d2695343534920      
naa.6001405ca26797ad544cd449cd8bead9                            vml.02000100006001405ca26797ad544cd449cd8bead9695343534920      
[root@esxi-02:~] esxcli storage core device world list -d naa.600140530f8f7a4dd969d4702d9397d2
[root@esxi-02:~] esxcli storage core device world list -d naa.6001405ca26797ad544cd449cd8bead9
Device                                World ID  Open Count  World Name
------------------------------------  --------  ----------  -------------------------
naa.6001405ca26797ad544cd449cd8bead9   2097193           1  idle0
naa.6001405ca26797ad544cd449cd8bead9   2097451           1  OCFlush
naa.6001405ca26797ad544cd449cd8bead9   2098353           1  res3HelperQueueVMFS6
naa.6001405ca26797ad544cd449cd8bead9   2098522           1  Vol3JournalExtendMgrWorld
naa.6001405ca26797ad544cd449cd8bead9   2099124           1  hostd
naa.6001405ca26797ad544cd449cd8bead9   2099806           1  hostd-worker
[root@esxi-02:~] esxcli iscsi adapter discovery rediscover -A vmhba64
Rediscovery started
[root@esxi-02:~]
```

Comment: what version one ESXi are you using?

Comment: Using 6.7 - It seems that I may have inadvertently deleted rather than unmounted the datastore

Comment: Rescued with what might be the most useful article ever written: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2046610

Answer (score 1):

Rescued with what might be the most useful article ever written: 
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2046610